# Is ">" (U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN) allowed inside an html-element attribute value?

Tags: html, regex, syntax

In other words may one use `/<tag[^>]*>.*?<\/tag>/` regex to match the `tag` html element which does not contain nested `tag` elements?

For example (lt.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>greater than sign in attribute value</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>1</div>
    <div title=">">2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regex:

```
$ perl -nE"say $1 if m~<div[^>]*>(.*?)</div>~" lt.html
```

And screen-scraper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin)
for div in soup.findAll('div'):
    print div.string


$ python lt.py <lt.html
```

Both give the same output:

```
1
">2
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
```

[w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes2) says:

> Attribute values are a mixture of text
>   and character references, except with
>   the additional restriction that the
>   text cannot contain an ambiguous
>   ampersand.

Comment: This is the textbook example everyone uses to explain why you shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML, you should use an HTML Parser.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed (W3C Validator accepts it, only issues a warning).

Unescaped `<` and `>` are also allowed inside comments, so such simple regexp can be fooled.

If BeautifulSoup doesn't handle this, it could be a bug or perhaps a conscious design decision to make it more resilient to missing closing quotes in attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Literal `>` is legal everywhere in html content, both inside attribute values and as text within an element.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that's valid, and the W3C validator agrees, but the authoritative source for this information is the ISO 8879:1986 standard, which costs ~150EUR/210USD.  Regardless, it is not wrong to encode them, so if in doubt, encode.  Additionally, if you are using an XML-based document type, you need to encode greater-than signs in the sequence `]]>`.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the following:

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

it looks like entity escapes are suggested everywhere (including in attributes) for < > and &

Comment: That document is wrong. Bare greater-than signs in content are valid. It also says that single ampersands are wrong, but this is not always the case for HTML.

Comment: It doesn't say greater-than signs are invalid, it just recommends using entities instead--a recommendation only a fool would ignore, IMO.  Who cares if it's valid, if most programmers, including the authors of many software tools, believe it isn't?

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using regular expressions (which is appropriate for basic string operations) try using `<tag((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)>.*?<\/tag>`. It should match attributes perfectly and therefore allowing you to access the inner content (although you need to put it in a capture group).

You may also use the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) for parsing HTML, which I would recommend if you are going to do a lot of parsing. Maintaining large regular expressions can easily become a headache, but in the meanwhile they are also much more effective if you are able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
yeah except /<tag[^>]*>.*?<\/tag>/
```

Will not match a single tag, but match the first start-tag and the last end-tag for a given tag. Just like your first non-greedy tag-match, your in-between should be written non-greedy as well.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you give an example?

Comment: @j-f-sebastian: <div class='foo'><span>flo</span><div>bar</div></div> you match first <div but also first </div

Answer (score 0):

see if you get the same result using &gt; instead of >