# Match e-mail addresses not contained in HTML tag

Tags: python, regex, email

I need to highlight an email addresses in text but not highlight them if contained in HTML tags, content, or attributes.

For example, the string `example@example.com` must be converted to `<a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a>`

But email addresses in the string `<a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a>` must not be processed.

I've tried something like this regexp:

`(?<![":])[a-zA-Z0-9._%-+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?!")`

but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401726/regex-that-only-matches-text-thats-not-part-of-html-markup-python

Answer (score 1):

I'll guessing that your source text is an HTML file which is missing anchor tags for only some of the contained e-mail addresses. If this is true, then you will not be able to use a regexp to reliably match only untagged e-mail addresses. For example, given the input:

```
...
<P>You'll find a lot more written by <A 
href="mailto:SvartaIF@example.com"
title="some text including an@sign.org">

SvartaIF@example.com
</A>.
</P>
...
```

it becomes impossible to lexically associate the `href` with the address and also exclude `an@sign.org`. You need to use an HTML parser; [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is pretty popular.