# .Net Function for Removing HTML from a String?

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex, parsing

I'm looking for a good function to remove HTML from a string of HTML. Ideas?

Comment: do you want to remove or to escape HTML?

Comment: Trying to remove it. I know this could result in some strange strings, but that's what I need to do with the system I'm integrating with. Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract text from resonably sane HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113651/how-to-extract-text-from-resonably-sane-html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not extensively tested this but found it a while back and has worked for my needs:

```
public static string StripTags(string html) {

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex objRegExp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<(.|\\n)+?>");
    return objRegExp.Replace(html, "");

}
```

Comment: It is worthwhile to note that due to the nature of HTML, it is impossible to write perfectly complete regular expressions to parse HTML.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601).

Comment: ok... converted it using [http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/].  Probably one of the best tool I use daily when google-ing code samples cause i always fine C# examples for things I need in VB.net

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for the info, even if it is not C#, I can easily convert from VB to C#. That basically worked for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: np man.  Like they said reg expressions wont always work (or any solution for that matter), especially because u will commonly find times programmers forgot to close their tags / etc, but it does work for the majority of situations.  Glad i was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [c-strip-xmlhtml-from-string](http://snipplr.com/view/20590/c-strip-xmlhtml-from-string/) or [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)