# RegEX style for HTML code

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Hey all, what would the regEX code be for the following:

```
<br/><span class=""synopsis-view-synopsis"">America's justice system comes under indictment in director <a href='/people/1035' class='actor' style='font-weight:bold'>Norman Jewison</a>'s trenchant film starring <a href='/people/1028' class='actor' style='font-weight:bold'>Al Pacino</a> as upstanding attorney Arthur Kirkland. A hard-line -- and tainted -- judge (<a href='/people/1034' class='actor' style='font-weight:bold'>John Forsythe</a>) stands accused of rape, and Kirkland (<a href='/people/1028' class='actor' style='font-weight:bold'>Al Pacino</a>) has to defend him. Kirkland has a history with the judge, who jailed one of the lawyer's clients on a technicality. When the judge confesses his guilt, Kirkland faces an ethical and legal quandary. </span>
```

Ive tried this:

```
regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<=""synopsis-view-synopsis""\>)([^<\/span><]+)")
```

But that only seems to get the first part of the description; **Americ**

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Comment: What part of "the following" are you trying to match? The inner text? The whole line? Certain tags? Something else? You may also want to ask yourself if this is something that could be made easier with an HTML parser, but I won't make any assumptions at this point...

Comment: Have a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181095/regular-expression-to-extract-text-from-html

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @eldarerathis: The inner text... **America's justice system comes....**

Comment: @JakubHampl has the right idea... [Beware of Zalgo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/135078)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any need for lookaheads or lookbehinds here; just match the whole `<span>` element and use a capturing group extract its content.  Assuming there will never be any `<span>` elements inside the one you're matching, this should be all you need:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(
    @"<span\s+class=""synopsis-view-synopsis"">(.*?)</span>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(s0))
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Also, `[^<\/span><]+` doesn't do what you probably think it does.  What you've got there is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any one character except `<`, `/`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `n`, or `>`.  You may have been trying for this:

```
(?:(?!</span>).)+
```

...which matches one character at a time, *after* the lookahead confirms that the character isn't the beginning of the sequence `</span>`.  It's a valid technique, but (as with the lookarounds) I don't think you need anything so fancy here.

Comment: That only seems to gather the first description and not any others following that one. I tried changing your **(.*?)** to **(.+?)** but that does not seem to work.

Comment: **First** description?  I don't see anything in the question about matching more than one of anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=""synopsis-view-synopsis""\>).+(?!<\/span>)
```

Should probably work. [Try using an HTML parser instead!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Didn't seem to work. There were 2 of them and it only displayed the first one and never found the second.

Comment: You didn't mention having two in your question. Change the `.+` to `.+?` and witch on a global flag. That should do the trick. Or use an HTML parser.

Comment: Did not get anything that time around changing **.+** to **.+?**

Comment: Then thats a problem in your code not in the regexp or possibly the fact that you are doing something with regexp that you are not supposed to.

Comment: I think the `(?=` at the start of this regex should be `(?<=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

in .net there are different methods for "match" and "matches all" these are:

```
re.Match(str);   // regex 're' match in string 'str'
re.Matches(str)  // regex 're' matches all in string 'str'
```

**update**

Explain to regex

- `(?<=regex)` is positive lookbehind
- `(?!regex)`  is a negativ lookahead
- `.+` finally matches anything between the lookaround

Raw Match Pattern:

```
(?<=""synopsis-view-synopsis""\>).+(?!</span>)
```

C#.NET Code Example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = 
            "<br/><span class=""synopsis-view-synopsis"">America's justice... </span>
             <br/><span class=""synopsis-view-synopsis"">Canada's justice... </span>";

          Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<=""""synopsis-view-synopsis""""\>).+(?!</span>)");
          MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
          int mIdx=0;
          foreach (Match m in mc)
           {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
              }
            mIdx++;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Matches Found:

```
[0][0] = America's justice... </span>
[1][0] = Canada's justice... </span>
```

Comment: @StealthRT see update. used this [regex tester](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php)