# grab TEXT ONLY from website

Tags: vb.net

How can i grab text ONLY from a website html but only the text and not the html?

i want to grab this site

http://kramansro.net/lunia/sites.html

i used this code

```
TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser2.DocumentText
```

But when i grab it it comes out like this

```
sdfasdfad<br>asdfasdfa<br>dfasdf<br>aasd<br>fs<br>dfa<br>sdf<br>asdf<br>asd<br>f<br>as
```

But i want it to be this:

```
sdfasdfad
asdfasdfa
dfasdf
aasd
fs
dfa
sdf
asdf
asd
f
as
```

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181095/regular-expression-to-extract-text-from-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the simplest method for that particular use case would be

```
TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser2.DocumentText.Replace("<br>", vbCrLf);
```

If you have more complex HTML, you should look into [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Nope my html is just what you see above

Comment: Well that was easy then :) Good luck.

Comment: Jordan That did nothing it didn't change any thing

TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser2.DocumentText
        WebBrowser2.DocumentText.Replace("<br>", vbCrLf)

Comment: Is there a way to replace the <br> with a new line?

Comment: @Austin I updated my answer to be a complete solution. All 1 line of it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Jordan You Rock! Worked