# Javascript Regex - affect only non html code? (ie text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a function that wraps text with a span

```
$(".ui-content").html(function (i, v) 
  {  
     return v.replace(/(CANADA)/gi, '<span class="query">$1</span>'); 
});
```

However when I pass in the term `"div"` or `"span"` or `"a"` which are html, the page gets messed up badly of course.

What can I change the `regex` to remove only text that is not part of a html code like `<strong>` but does work on `A strong person is a helpful friend`

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181095/regular-expression-to-extract-text-from-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same concept, as @elclanrs, but with an imitation of negative look behind:

```
$(".ui-content").html(function (i, v) {       
     return v.replace(/([^</])(strong)/gi, ' <span class="query">$2</span> ');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39VMe/

Also a good article about how to treat certain limitations of JavaScript regexp: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Node manipulations to the rescue, as always!

```
function toArray(obj) {
    var r = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        r.push(obj[i]);
    }

    return r;
}

$('.ui-content').each(function() {
    var stack = [this];
    var c, n;

    while(c = stack.pop()) {
        var childNodes = toArray(c.childNodes);

        for(var i = 0; n = childNodes[i]; i++) {
            if(n.nodeType === 1) {
                stack.push(n);
            } else if(n.nodeType === 3) {
                var matches = n.nodeValue.split(/(CANADA)/i);

                for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
                    var newNode;

                    if(/CANADA/i.test(matches[i])) {
                        newNode = document.createElement('span');
                        newNode.className = 'query';
                        newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(matches[i]));
                    } else {
                        newNode = document.createTextNode(matches[i]);
                    }

                    n.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, n);
                }

                n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Here's a demo jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/Ckhk5/)

Comment: ++1 just because I will use it for awesomely different purpose `:)` cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit: Wait a minute... it doesn't entirely work... maybe. (I *had* a typo, but jsFiddle isn't responding now.)

Comment: Neah I needed a Node manipulation code start I am using this sample what a coincidence! + 1 `:)` I will make it work man all good keep my +1 ; anyhoo favouriting OP's question

Comment: I wont be using it for regex purpose, thanks anyways bruv! thnx `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I know people usually insist in not using regex for parsing html but hey this seems to work just fine. This uses a negative lookahead to replace only the word "strong" and not actual `<strong>` tags:

```
/strong(?!>)/
```

**Edit:**

Use this regex which is more flexible and allows for attributes:

```
/strong(?!(>|\s\w+=))/g;
```

In any case, it all depends on your HTML. If regex don't do it then you'll have to parse properly.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mGLjb/2/

Comment: This regexp will not work if the **strong** tag has any attributes. In typical HTML negative look behind would work better. But it is not supported in JS.

Comment: Oh I see, didn't really test other options but I updated the regex and example it should work fine now