# Parsing HTML - Getting the paragraph with the most text

Tags: c#, html, regex, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to parse a HTML page (The page isn't known and changes often, however they are always news sites). Basically, I need to pull the news out of a bunch of code downloaded from the site, which i'm trying to do with a regex like this:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(x.Result, @"<p>(.+?)</p>");
```

Obvious bad idea - it pulls down anything tagged as a paragraph.

Any better ways to pull a news article or large body of text, separated from the code, from a website?

Comment: post some input and expected output

Comment: Can you look for any classes or ids that may assist in deciphering if the data inside the tag is useful to you?

Comment: ^To add to the point above, use a HTML parsing library to select the tag and ask it to strip all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be exactly what you want (you haven't provided a lot of detail), but you can strip all tags from a page with a pair of simple regex's.

Remove javascript and CSS:

```
<(script|style).*?</\1>
```

Remove tags

```
<.*?>
```

[Credit goes to this existing answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/181105/4051639) What you will be left with is the "plain text" from the page.