# get rid of an HTML symbol using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex which searches successfully for a text inside an HTML code given a keyword however I cannot get rid of the symbol `<` or `>`

This is my regex:

```
[><][^><=]*climate[> - <][^<|//]*
```

And this the result:

```
>Formation of coastal sea ice in North Pacific drives ocean circulation and climate<
```

any suggestion please?

Comment: What program are you using to parse this? what style of regex? also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181095/regular-expression-to-extract-text-from-html

Comment: Try `<.*>(.*)</.*>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2864740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add look ahead and lookbehind instead of matching them:

```
(?<=[><])[^><=]*climate(?=[> - <])[^<|/]*
^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/FgiKN8/2)

Comment: Works perfect thank you soo much! and thanks for explanation!

Comment: @jim Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `[^<>]*climate`as regex, that should do the trick.
Or did I misunderstand your question?

Nice helper for testing and building regex: http://regexr.com/