# Removing Tags from HTML Parsed with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse a website and then extract data. I have the following code:

```
for line in raw_data: #raw_data is the parsed html separated into smaller blocks
    d = {}
    d['name'] = line.find('div', {'class':'torrentname'}).find('a')
    print d['name']

<a href="/ubuntu-9-10-desktop-i386-t3144211.html">
<strong class="red">Ubuntu</strong> 9.10 desktop (i386)</a>
```

Normally I would be able extract 'Ubuntu 9.10 desktop (i386)' by writing:

```
d['name'] = line.find('div', {'class':'torrentname'}).find('a').string
```

but due to the strong html tags it returns None. Is there a way to extract the strong tags and then use .string or is there a better way? I have tried using BeautifulSoup's extract() function but I couldn't get it to work.

Edit: I just realized that my solution does not work if there are two sets of strong tags as the space between the words are left out. What would be a way to fix this problem?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598817/python-html-removal/599080#599080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ".text" property:

```
d['name'] = line.find('div', {'class':'torrentname'}).find('a').text
```

Or do a join on findAll(text=True):

```
anchor = line.find('div', {'class':'torrentname'}).find('a')
d['name'] = ''.join(anchor.findAll(text=True))
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't keep the spaces in an example like this: <strong class="red">Ubuntu</strong> <strong class="red">Linux</strong>. It comes out as UbuntuLinux.

Comment: Thanks so much, that works great! Could you explain how that second line of code works?

Comment: The BeautifulSoup documentation says the text argument allows you to "search for NavigableString objects instead of Tags". findAll returns a python list, which can then be joined together (.join) to form one string.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html