# Remove HTML tags and unwanted information in Python With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to Python and I am in the process of parsing the contents of a webpage with BeautifulSoup. The webpage is https://www.ranker.com/crowdranked-list/the-greatest-rappers-of-all-time if that matters. I want to make a list of the top 25 rappers. I managed to find the path with the rappers name, but cannot get rid of the HTML tags and other nested information. Is there a way to iterate over the list, to only display the name of the artist?

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.ranker.com/crowdranked-list/the-greatest-rappers-of-all-time')
```

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'})
results 
[<meta content="Ranker" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Eminem" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Tupac" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="The Notorious B.I.G." itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Kendrick Lamar" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Nas" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Dr. Dre" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Lil Wayne" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="J. Cole" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Ice Cube" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Snoop Dogg" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Jay-Z" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Kanye West" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="André 3000" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="50 Cent" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Eazy-E" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="DMX" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Drake" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="ASAP Rocky" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Busta Rhymes" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Kid Cudi" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Ghostface Killah" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Chance the Rapper" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Childish Gambino" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Nate Dogg" itemprop="name"/>,
 <meta content="Logic" itemprop="name"/>]
```

Basically I want to have this output (but for all 25 artists), which works with a single item in the list:

```
first_result = results[1]

print(first_result['content'])

Eminem
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Tags from HTML Parsed with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585725/removing-tags-from-html-parsed-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: It does not, unfortunately.

Comment: Loop over each tag and extract it's content: `[meta["content"] for meta in results]`

Answer (score 1):

loop and use `.get('content')`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.ranker.com/crowdranked-list/the-greatest-rappers-of-all-time')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'})
# get the names of the rappers
names = [result.get('content') for result in results]
names
```

output:

> ```
> ['Ranker',
>  'Eminem',
>  'Tupac',
>  'The Notorious B.I.G.',
>  'Kendrick Lamar',
>  'Nas',
>  ...
>  'Logic']
> ```